# Scheduling a job in React Hooks inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm writing a kibana plugin and I'm facing some trouble with a scheduled function: I want to refresh my page (and getting information from the server) every 5 seconds and to do that I wrote a setInterval inside the useEffect that calls my refresh function.

Now, if I call the refresh function manually (with a button), it works fine, the states are valued correctly and so on. But if I call the refresh function inside the setInterval inside the useEffect, it's like the state are never setted. The hooks set the various state but after 5 seconds, to the next refresh call, the states are empty.

Code, very simple:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  refresh();
  setInterval(refresh, 5 * 1000); //called from here, the states are empty, called manually works fine 
                                  // and the states are filled correctly
}, []}

const refresh = () => {
//some code with various states update
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). The answer here very much depends on what `refresh` does. If it just uses setters and not other things it closes over, it should work. If it uses other state it closes over, it'll use stale state.

Answer (score 0):

The `refresh` function is created every render, but the `useEffect` runs only on first mount, so when the interval runs, `refresh` is in a stale closure - any state referenced inside `refresh` will refer to initial state only.

One option would be to have the interval call a function in a *ref* instead, a ref which gets set when the state changes and has a reference to the state currently being rendered:

```
const refreshRef = useRef();
refreshRef.current = useCallback(() => {
  //some code with various states update
}, [valueA, valueB]);
// Put all stateful values referenced in the callback into the dependency array

// If you want to clear the interval when the component unmounts:
const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState();
useEffect(()=>{
  refreshRef.current()
  setIntervalId(
    setInterval(() => refreshRef.current(), 5 * 1000)
  );
  return () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}, []);
```

Example working snippet:

```js
const { useState, useRef, useCallback, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const refreshRef = useRef();
  refreshRef.current = useCallback(() => {
    //some code with various states update
    console.log(count);
  }, [count]);
  // Put all stateful values referenced in the callback into the dependency array

  // If you want to clear the interval when the component unmounts:
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState();
  useEffect(()=>{
    refreshRef.current()
    setIntervalId(
      setInterval(() => refreshRef.current(), 5 * 1000)
    );
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

It looks like you can't do

```
const refresh = useCallback(...
```

and then call `refresh` inside a `useEffect` which depends on `refresh` because then the timing of when the interval function would be disrupted whenever the state changes; in the example below, rather than the `count` being logged every 5 seconds, it's logged every 5 seconds *and* every time state changes. If you wanted to make sure the log occurred on mount, then 5 seconds after mount, then 10 seconds after mount, etc, regardless of state updates, you'd have to do some ugly messing around with timestamps - unless you used the `useRef` approach in my first snippet.

```js
const { useState, useCallback, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const refresh = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(count);
  }, [count]);
  // Put all stateful values referenced in the callback into the dependency array

  // If you want to clear the interval when the component unmounts:
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState();
  useEffect(()=>{
    refresh();
    // Clear the existing interval, if another one is pending:
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    setIntervalId(
      setInterval(refresh, 5 * 1000)
    );
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, [refresh]);
  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Or, without a dependency array in the `useEffect`, the `refresh` function it references would be in a stale closure on subsequent renders:

```js
const { useState, useCallback, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const refresh = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(count);
  }, [count]);
  // Put all stateful values referenced in the callback into the dependency array

  // If you want to clear the interval when the component unmounts:
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState();
  useEffect(()=>{
    refresh();
    // Clear the existing interval, if another one is pending:
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    setIntervalId(
      setInterval(refresh, 5 * 1000)
    );
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: why do you assign the memoized callback to a ref? also, I believe the effect will leak memory unless you provide an unsubscribe function.

Comment: @kyle Setting it to a ref allows the `setInterval` to be called exactly once, when the component is initially rendered, with a stable reference to a ref (function) with the current stateful values. I guess you could also do `setInterval` and `clearInterval` every time the values change, and check `Date.now()` and the time until the next callback needs to run, but that'd be pretty convoluted IMO

Comment: The `useCallback` isn't *needed* above, but it's a bit more elegant than creating the callback anew each render

Comment: I see, how would that be different than just `const refresh = useCallback(() => {}, [...]);`? And then having the `refresh` variable be a dependency of the effect?

Comment: With that approach, the interval would have to be set and cleared on render when state changes, and you'd also have to keep a persistent state of the time the last interval ran, and compare against the current time, in order to figure out what to pass as the timeout time when calling the next interval. You'd then have to reset the interval time to 5000 after the first runs, if no re-renders have occurred in the meantime. Possible, but messier than the alternative in my answer, I think.

Comment: That is actually incorrect. The effect would only run when the refresh dependency changes, and then the callback would would be recreated/change whenever it's own dependencies change. If neither are changed they are memoized between renders and not recreated, meaning the interval wouldn't need to be set + cleared on each render, only on the initial mount and dismount.

Comment: I made a few snippets. The first works, the second tries to use your approach with `refresh` as an effect dependency, the third does the same without any effect dependency. One of those was what you were thinking of, right? But the second's callback doesn't run at the desired time of "every 5 seconds" (but rather, at "on every render, and on every 5 seconds after the last re-render), and the third's callback is in a stale closure. If there's a more elegant solution I'd really like to know if I'm missing something - want to post an answer?

Comment: this is what I had in mind https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-sun-8gfnc?file=/src/IntervalComp.js